# Views block content hidden from visitor

Tags: 7, views, commerce

I have created a view in a regular Drupal installation with the commerce modules requiered to run a web shop, so far everything is running smooth. I then create a couple of blocks to present the product information using the Views module in the product display node. All blocks show me the right content when login as admin of the site, but I soon as I logout one of the block content is not shown.

I check the page source code and the block wrap and the table formatter display are rendered, but there is not content as a visitor of the site. What am I missing?

Note: there are not errors log in Drupal watchdog or in Apache or PHP.

Comment: check views permissions and anonymous permissions

Comment: First thing to check was that. So far I have noticed that the issue seems to come from when I do a relationship to the "Referenced product"